# Get data-attribute of an element by another data-attribute as identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have dynamically created elements with no id, but a data-attribute id like: `data-jobtypid="2"`.

This dynamically created element has other data-attributes, which I would like to read and I only know the `data-jobtypid` as identifier and the classname of all dynamically created elements.

So I tryed something like this:

```
var cache_color = $('.addjob_choose_paymentbtn')
                   .filter('[data-jobtypid="2"]')
                   .getAttribute("data-jobtypcolorhover");
```

Has someone an idea for me to solve this?

Regards

Comment: Change `getAttribute()` to `attr()` which is the jQuery attribute getter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) combined with [`$.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2):

```js
var cache_color = $('.addjob_choose_paymentbtn[data-jobtypid="2"]')
  .data('jobtypcolorhover');

console.log(cache_color);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addjob_choose_paymentbtn" data-jobtypid="2" data-jobtypcolorhover="red">div</div>
```

You can alternatively use `.attr('data-jobtypcolorhover')`, which is the correct way to access an attribute in jQuery as mentioned in the comments above. However, `$.data()` is a tiny beat cleaner.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```js
let c= document.querySelector('.addjob_choose_paymentbtn[data-jobtypid="2"]')
         .dataset.jobtypcolorhover;

console.log(c);
```

```html
<div class="addjob_choose_paymentbtn" data-jobtypid="2" data-jobtypcolorhover="blue">Hi</div>
```